# Concatenating files with matching string in middle of filename

Tags: python, python-2.7

My goal is to concatenate files in a folder based on a string in the middle of the filename, ideally using python or bash. To simplify the question, here is an example:

- P16C-X128-22MB-LL_merged_trimmed.fastq
- P16C-X128-27MB-LR_merged_trimmed.fastq
- P16C-X1324-14DL-UL_merged_trimmed.fastq
- P16C-X1324-21DL-LL_merged_trimmed.fastq

I would like to concatenate based on the value after the first dash but before the second (e.g. X128 or X1324), so that I am left with (in this example), two additional files that contain the concatenated contents of the individual files:

- P16C-X128-Concat.fastq (concat of 2 files with X128)
- P16C-X1324-Concat.fastq (concat of 2 files with X1324)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Slayther I tried a few things with bash, but not even worth posting those failures. My python is *incredibly* limited, so wasn't sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple string manipulations, I prefer to avoid the use of regular expressions. I think that `str.split()` is enough in this case. Besides, for simple file name matching, the library `fnmatch` provides enough functionality.

```
import fnmatch
import os
from itertools import groupby

path = '/full/path/to/files/'
ext = ".fastq"
files = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(path), '*' + ext)

def by(fname): return fname.split('-')[1] # Ej. X128
# You said:
# I would like to concatenate based on the value after the first dash
# but before the second (e.g. X128 or X1324)
# If you want to keep both parts together, uncomment the following: 
# def by(fname): return '-'.join(fname.split('-')[:2]) # Ej. P16C-X128

for k, g in groupby(sorted(files, key=by), key=by):
    dst = str(k) + '-Concat' + ext 
    with open(os.path.join(path, dst), 'w') as dstf:
        for fname in g:
            with open(os.path.join(path, fname), 'r') as srcf:
                dstf.write(srcf.read())
```

Instead of the read, write in Python, you could also delegate the concatenation to the OS. You would normally use a bash command like this:

```
cat *-X128-*.fastq > X128.fastq
```

Using the `subprocess` library:

```
import subprocess

for k, g in groupby(sorted(files, key=by), key=by):
    dst = str(k) + '-Concat' + ext 
    with open(os.path.join(path, dst), 'w') as dstf:
        command = ['cat']                                   # +++
        for fname in g:
            command.append(os.path.join(path, fname))       # +++
        subprocess.run(command, stdout=dstf)                # +++
```

Also, for a batch job like this one, you should consider placing the concatenated files in a separate directory, but that is easily done by changing the `dst` filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open` to read and write (create) files, `os.listdir` to get all files (and directories) in a certain directory and `re` to match file name as needed.

Use a dictionary to store contents by filename prefix (the file's name up until 3rd hyphen `-`) and concatenate the contents together.

```
import os
import re

contents = {}
file_extension = "fastq"

# Get all files and directories that are in current working directory
for file_name in os.listdir('./'):

    # Use '.' so it doesn't match directories
    if file_name.endswith('.' + file_extension):

        # Match the first 2 hyphen-separated values from file name
        prefix_match = re.match("^([^-]+\-[^-]+)", file_name)
        file_prefix = prefix_match.group(1)

        # Read the file and concatenate contents with previous contents
        contents[file_prefix] = contents.get(file_prefix, '')
        with open(file_name, 'r') as the_file:
            contents[file_prefix] += the_file.read() + '\n'

# Create new file for each file id and write contents to it
for file_prefix in contents:
    file_contents = contents[file_prefix]
    with open(file_prefix + '-Concat.' + file_extension, 'w') as the_file:
        the_file.write(file_contents)
```